# TFS post commit to redmine

Tags: visual-studio, tfs, redmine

I have a TFS 2010 source control. I want to send post commit description to redmine.
I do not have control of source control.
I probably need a Visual Studio plugin for doing that.

Comment: Could you elaborate your question? Do you mean you want to integrate TFS with Redmine?

Comment: I just want to send post commit description into redmine issue. like when it start with #1234, add the commit description to redmine issu 1234.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There is not a default way to integrate TFS and Redmine. To integrate you will either have to develop your own or buy a tool.

If you want to develop your own tool, [TFS Integration tools](https://tfsintegration.codeplex.com/) will give you some help.